# How to reconnect ReactorNettyWebSocketClient connection?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I need to access a websocket-service which closes an open websocket-connection after 24h. How do I have to implement the reconnect with Spring-Boot 2 and Webflux?

This is what I have so far (taken from https://github.com/artembilan/webflux-websocket-demo):

```
@GetMapping(path = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> getStreaming() throws URISyntaxException {
    ReactorNettyWebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();

    EmitterProcessor<String> output = EmitterProcessor.create();

    Mono<Void> sessionMono = client.execute(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/echo"),

    session -> session.receive()
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
    .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
    .subscribeWith(output)
    .then());

    return output.doOnSubscribe(s -> sessionMono.subscribe());
}
```

As soon as the connection gets lost (3 seconds no input anymore), a TimeoutException is thrown. But how can I reconnect the socket?

Answer (score 5):

There is no out-of-the-box solution, reconnection mechanism is not part of JSR 356 - Java API for WebSocket. But you can implement it on your own - a simple example with Spring events:

**Step 1 - Create an event class.**

```
public class ReconnectionEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private String url;

    public ReconnectionEvent(String url) {
        super(url);
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

}
```

**Step 2 - Provide a method for websocket connection.** An example:

```
...
@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
...
public void connect(String url) {

    ReactorNettyWebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();

    EmitterProcessor<String> output = EmitterProcessor.create();

    Mono<Void> sessionMono = client.execute(URI.create(url),

            session -> session.receive()
                    .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                    .log()
                    .subscribeWith(output)
                    .doOnTerminate(() -> publisher.publishEvent(new ReconnectEvent(url)))
                    .then());

    output
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> sessionMono.subscribe())
            .subscribe();
}
```

Check `doOnTerminate()` method - when the Flux terminates, either by completing successfully or with an error, it emits a ReconnectEvent. If necessary, you can emit the reconnection event on other Flux's callbacks (for example only on `doOnError()`).

**Step 3 - Provide a listener, that connects again on given url when a reconnection event occures.**

```
@EventListener(ReconnectEvent.class)
public void onApplicationEvent(ReconnectEvent event) {
    connect(event.getUrl());
}
```

Comment: Hi @joanna, thanks a lot - I'll check that out soon!

Comment: Can't `doOnTerminate` be simplified to `() -> connect(url)`? What is the reason for needing to send out an application event?

Comment: That's a good point by @wild_nothing, why make it complicated?

Answer (score 2):

I did something by using `UnicastProcessor` of reactor.

```
...
public abstract class AbstractWsReconnectClient {
    private Logger ...

    protected UnicastProcessor<AbstractWsReconnectClient> reconnectProcessor = UnicastProcessor.create();

    protected AbstractWsReconnectClient(Duration reconnectDuration) {
        reconnect(reconnectDuration);
    }

    public abstract Mono<Void> connect();

    private void reconnect(Duration duration) {
        reconnectProcessor.publish()
            .autoConnect()
            .delayElements(duration)
            .flatMap(AbstractWsReconnectClient::connect)
            .onErrorContinue(throwable -> true,
                (throwable, o) -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof ConnectException) {
                        logger.warn(throwable.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        logger.error("unexpected error occur during websocket reconnect");
                        logger.error(throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                })
            .doOnTerminate(() -> logger.error("websocket reconnect processor terminate "))
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```

When the `WebSocketClient` is terminate, invoke `UnicastProcessor.onNext`

```
public Mono<Void> connect() {
    WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
    logger.info("trying to connect to sso server {}", uri.toString());
    return client.execute(uri, headers, ssoClientHandler)
        .doOnTerminate(() -> {
            logger.warn("sso server {} disconnect", uri.toString());
            super.reconnectProcessor.onNext(this);
        });
}
```

Comment: UnicastProcessor is deprecated. Use rather `Sinks.Many<String> reconnectManager = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();` and `reconnectManager.asFlux().publish()` or `reconnectManager.tryEmitOn(this)`